# Find Source Image Info for Deployed Azure Server

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

Is there a way to find the ***Source Image*** info for a deployed VM which is displayed in the Azure Portal;

Virtual Machines\VMName\Disks\Overview

Reads something like - *MicrosoftWindowsServer / WindowsServer/....*

I would like to get this via AzureRM Powershell commands only.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show the version number.

```
(Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName TestRG -VMName Dev2012R2).StorageProfile.ImageReference

OutPut:

Publisher : MicrosoftWindowsServer
Offer     : WindowsServer
Sku       : 2012-R2-Datacenter
Version   : latest
Id
```

Comment: Thanks !

Is there anyway of finding out what the 'latest' is? 

As the machine might have been deployed in 2017 which is no longer the latest